# How to pass fetched data to getServerSideProps function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using Context API to fetch data and then pass data to **getServerSideProps** function but I'm having the following error:

`React Hook "useContext" is called in function "getServerSideProps" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function`

Here's my code:

**AppContext.tsx**:

```
export const AppContext = createContext(null);
export const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/users');
      const body = await response.json();
      setData(body.users);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={data}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then in my **index.tsx** file (path:  apps/ui/pages/index.tsx)
I have this code:

```
const Home: NextPage<HomeProps> = ({ tiers }) => {
  const data = useAppContext();
  console.log('data', data); // This prints the data just fine

  return (
    <Box>
      <Head>
        <title>React App</title>
      </Head>
      {data?.map((user) => (
        .....
        />
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // const data = useContext(AppContext); // Here I get the error message I mentioned above
  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}

export default Home;
```

so How can I receive the data coming from my Context file inside my **getServerSideProps** function and **NOT** having to use the context straight in my Home component?

**NOTE:** I do have a partial fix, BUT I don't want to do it in index.tsx file because I want the data to come from my Context.

Here's my partial fix, in index.tsx I have this function:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/users');
  const body = await response.json();
  return body.users;
};
```

and inside getServerSideProps function I have this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const data = await fetchData();

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}
```

and inside Home component I'm just passing it as a prop like this:

```
const Home: NextPage<HomeProps> = ({ data }) => (..)
```

Comment: `getServerSideProps` is not a react component so you cannot use `useContext`. Try putting it inside `NextPage`?

Comment: Yup I know getServerSideProps is not a react component, also I don't have straight access to NextPage as this is control by NextJS

Comment: Sorry I think I meant `Home`

Comment: @evolutionxbox well I'm inside the Home component, so can you provide a solution? Thanks

Comment: `getServerSideProps` runs solely on the server and is _not_ isomorphic. It doesn't have access to the DOM and is not any type of React component, so you can use a hook there. You'll have to manually fetch the data.

Comment: @code could you provide and post a solution, please? thanks

Comment: I'm afraid what you're trying to do is not possible. If I interpret your question correctly, you're trying to access client data on the server, which cannot be done unless the client explicitly passes it to the server.

Comment: @code I'm trying to fetch data from Context that calls and API and then somehow pass that data to getServerSideProps so this function can pass it down to Home component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @code is saying is correct, you have a context that fetches data clientside and you want to use this data in getServerSideProps. You are trying to magically pass clientside data to the server without making a request. The problem here is that you are misinterpreting the data flow with getServerSideProps.

With getServerSideProps you generate some data (props) on the server and then pass them to to the page so react can render on the server.

getServerSideProps only runs when you request the page (a GET request) and it runs before any react code, hence why you cannot access your context data.

The partial solution you have is correct but instead of making a fetch call, import the logic from this route `/api/users` inside getServerSideProps. This will save you a duplicate call to your server.